# How to keep child divs from expanding beyond the parent when printing

Tags: css, printing, css-print

I am trying to format an html page as a court pleading which needs to print neatly on an 8.5 x 11 piece of paper. I have it looking to spec as an HTML, but when I go to print, the Container holding the contents expands beyond the body.

I have tried setting a specific width to the container to match the body, but that has not worked.

I created a fiddle with both the HTML and CSS:

[See fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vtLorax/8p41te2v/8/)

Here is the CSS for the BODY and CONTAINER:

```
body {
    width: 8.5in;
    height: 11in;
    padding-left: 1.5in;
    padding-right: .5in;
    margin: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid grey;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.container {
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    width: 8.5in;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

If you click on the "Open print preview" text at the bottom of the result, and then attempt to print, you can see how the document changes in the print preview window in Chrome.

This application is meant to work in Chrome specifically. I am trying to produce a document that looks similar to the following, with the grey thinner lines indicating the edge of the page:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the [solution](https://codepen.io/mobarak/pen/byOVGg) which you are looking for. I tested your code in different browser's **print preview**  functionality and found different result. Then I stick with google chrome and coded accordingly.

I found you used same code twice so it was not working properly! I put the other code for `screen only`. and change the following code for `print`

```
 @media print {
    body {
        /* width: 8.5in; */
        /* height: 11in; */
        margin: 0;
        border-left: 1px solid gray;
        border-right: 1px solid gray;
        /*Newly added codes */
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .container {
        border-left: 2px solid black;
        border-right: 2px solid black;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px;
        height: 100%;
        /*Newly added codes  */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /* Copied from body */
        padding-left: 1.5in;
        padding-right: .5in;
    }
}
```

In my code I removed the `textarea`, instead I put a `<p>` tag with editable capability. Please review the code and let me know your opinion.

And this is what I have here in Google Chrome.

[image]

---

I tried several option but not found any proper one! But this one is tricky! Just used the following code for `print` CSS. Please replace and test this code.

```
@media print {
    body {
        /* width: 8.5in; */
        /* height: 11in; */
        padding-left: 1.5in;
        padding-right: .5in;
        margin: 0;
        border-left: 1px solid gray;
        border-right: 1px solid gray;
        /*Newly added codes */
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .container {
        border-left: 2px solid black;
        border-right: 2px solid black;
        width: 6.5in;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10pt 36pt;
        /* height: 100%; */
        /*Newly added codes  */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /* Copied from body */
    }
}
```

After that I used the custom margin in google chrome (Though I have not printed it! So you better test it for final output).
[image]

Hopefully this will satisfy your need! :)

Comment: This is a step closer, but I am looking for the lines to print on the page.

Comment: I just added a picture to my question. The <p> text box is a nice touch.

Comment: all borders or the middle black borders only! Printing the borders at the edge may be   tricky as the printer may eat up some space. So it may not be visible at all. but middle black border is achievable.

Comment: Middle black borders only. The grey borders were just to show where I'd want the edge of the page to be. How do you get to print preview for the result frame only from codepen?

Comment: Do you want the border like your picture or with  specific measurement.

Comment: My picture was made with specific widths in CSS. I am looking for there to be 1.5 inches on the left, and a 1/2 inch on the right. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I used some @media print CSS and just made the page and font larger to correct the skewing in print preview. That worked on at least my browser without adjusting margins at printing--which I have to avoid for a user friendly solution.